# Angular Timer to count the time

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a timer to count the time from 0.

However, when I click the button the time is not counting, does anyone know why?

How can I get this timer in this format {{hours}}: {{mminutes}}: {{sseconds}}?

Thanks!

**My code**

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fojamd)

**Component.ts**

```
time: number = 0;
interval;

startTimer() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        if(this.time = 0) {
            this.time++;
        } else {
            this.time= 0;
        }
    },1000)
}

pauseTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

Comment: You have an assigment in your if statement..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you like this **date: 'mm:ss'** in html

**Component**

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  time: number = 0;
  display ;
  interval;

 startTimer() {
    console.log("=====>");
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.time === 0) {
        this.time++;
      } else {
        this.time++;
      }
      this.display=this.transform( this.time)
    }, 1000);
  }
  transform(value: number): string {
       const minutes: number = Math.floor(value / 60);
       return minutes + ':' + (value - minutes * 60);
  }
  pauseTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button (click)='startTimer()'>Start Timer</button>
<button (click)='pauseTimer()'>Pause</button>

<p>{{display }} Seconds</p>
```

**Edit:**
**'mm:ss'**

```
transform(value: number): string {
           const minutes: number = Math.floor(value / 60);
           return minutes + ':' + (value - minutes * 60);
      }
```

**{HH:MM:SS} format**

```
transform(value: number): string {
      var sec_num = value; 
    var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    if (hours   < 10) {hours   = 0;}
    if (minutes < 10) {minutes = 0;}
    if (seconds < 10) {seconds = 0;}
    return hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I used the function to get the hours, minutes and seconds (the last) but the time only starts to appear from 10 seconds. Everything else is perfect

Comment: remove this if (seconds < 10) {seconds = 0;} to start from 0

Answer (score 3):

in your component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, timer } from 'rxjs';

const counter = timer(0, 1000);

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  public clock;

  ngOnInit() {
    counter.subscribe(() => {
      this.time();
    });
  }

  time() {
    let date = new Date();
    let second:number | string = date.getSeconds();
    let minute:number | string = date.getMinutes();
    let hour:number | string = date.getHours();
    if (second < 10) {
      second = '0' + second
    }
    if (minute < 0) {
      minute = '0' + minute;
    }
    this.clock = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
  }

}
```

in your html:

```
<p>
  {{clock}}
</p>
```

Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/timerobservable

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.I hope it will helps you.

```
 time: number = 0;
  interval;

  startTimer() {
    console.log("=====>");
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.time === 0) {
        this.time++;
      } else {
        this.time++;
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
  pauseTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }


transform(value: number, args?: any): string {

    const hours: number = Math.floor(value / 60);
    const minutes: number = (value - hours * 60);

    if (hours < 10 && minutes < 10) {
        return '0' + hours + ' : 0' + (value - hours * 60);
    }
    if (hours > 10 && minutes > 10) {
        return '0' + hours + ' : ' + (value - hours * 60);
    }
    if (hours > 10 && minutes < 10) {
        return hours + ' : 0' + (value - hours * 60);
    }
    if (minutes > 10) {
        return '0' + hours + ' : ' + (value - hours * 60);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<button (click)='startTimer()'>Start Timer</button>
<button (click)='pauseTimer()'>Pause</button>

<p>{{transform(time)}}</p>
```

Comment: It worked, how can I now get it in the desired format? 'hh: mm: ss'

Comment: You should consider using a library like "date-fns" (https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns) for formatting your date strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
time: number = 0;
interval;

startTimer() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        if(this.time === 0) {
            this.time++;
        } else {
            this.time= 0;
        }
    },1000)
}

pauseTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

Try this.